# User profile data does not appear after logging in

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies

I am creating a social network website where each user has his own profile, but there is a problem when I log in, the profile page does not appear. I used cookies and sessions I did lot of research about the problem but without any success, so I think that the problem is in the cookies. I do not know how to fix it; if anyone can help me, I will appreciate that.

## profile.php

```
<?php  
ob_start();
require_once('for members/scripts/global.php'); 

if($logged == 1){
 echo("you need to be loged in to view profiles");
 exit();
}
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
 $id=$_GET['id'];
 $id= preg_replace("#[^0-9]#","",$id);

}else{
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
}
//collect member information
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id='$id'LIMIT 1") or die("could not collect user information ");
$count_mem = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count_mem == 0){
 echo("the user does not exit");
 exit();

}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  $username = $row['username'];
  $fname = $row['firstname'];
  $lname = $row['lastname'];
  $profile_id= $row['id'];

  if($session_id == $profile_id){
  $owner = true;
  }else{
   $owner = false;

  }

}



?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php print("$fname"); ?> <?php print("$lname"); ?>'s profile</title>
<link href="style/stylesheet.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container center"> 
<h1><?php print("$username"); ?></h1>
<?php
if($owner == true ){
    header("Location: profile.php");
?>
<!--
<a href="#">edit profile</a><br />
<a href="#">account settings</a><br />
-->
<?php
}else{
    header("Location: index.php");
?>
<!--
<a href="#">private message</a><br />
<a href="#">add as friend</a><br />
--> 
<?php
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php flush(); ?>
```

If you need other related code, let me know. Thank you.

Comment: You have to use `session_start` before you can use session variables.

Comment: you mean that in the first of the his code i need to write session_start??

Comment: put `session_start()` in the first line, to log off a user put `$_SESSION=array(); session_destroy();` Potential security problem: accessing user-data by $_GET, can be easily fooled. Better do $_SESSION['id'].

Comment: You say that it doesn't show the profile... but you have some die statements in there, so what do you see when trying to view the profile?

Comment: it redirect me to the index .php even thoug iam loging in with a valid data  it appear that it do not reconnize it

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things wrong with the code that you have displayed.  For starters, **Do not use `mysql_` functions.**  From the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Secondly, your `header` redirects are imbedded in your HTML, which is bad practice and you've only been saved by `ob_start()`.  With that though, you have a conditional that will either redirect to 'profile.php' or 'index.php', be lucky you get redirected to 'index.php', otherwise you'd have a forever self-redirecting page.

I can't see if/where you ever set the variable `$session_id`, but from what can be seen, it's `null` and will never `== $profile_id`, so `$owner` will always be `false`.

With that, you have a `while` loop while fetching one row...remove it, no need for it.

Now for some of the logic in your code.  If you have to be the profile owner in order to view it, check that immediately after your query, and if not the owner, `header("Location: index.php"); die;` and don't have an `else`, anything following it means that it's the profile owner viewing the page.

Also, you need to make sure `session_start();` is at the top of the page if you plan on using the session variables.  You have `ob_start();` up there, but at the end you call `flush()`.  Read up on [ob_start()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and call the proper flush function for the buffer you started.